# Least $\alpha>\omega$ such that $V_{\alpha}$ satisfies certain ZF axioms

Tags: set-theory

In my text i found this question:

*Which is the least $ \alpha > \omega$ such that $V_{\alpha}$ satisfies the **axiom of power**? which the least for satisfies the **axiom of pairing**? And the **axiom of infinity?** And **all three together**?*

So, I try to say what I know:

- $V_{\omega}$ doesn't satisfy axiom of infinity, but $V_{\omega+1}$ does.
- $V_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies power, infinity and pairing, so *maybe* (is it the least?) it s solves "all three"

Then, what?

Comment: Can any $V_{\omega + n}, n<\omega$, satisfy the powerset axiom? or pairing?

Comment: To expand on BrianO's comment - suppose that $\delta$ is a successor ordinal.  Then can you show that $V_\delta$ doesn't satisfy the power set axiom?

Comment: are you trying to say that $V_{\alpha}$ satisfy power axiom iff alpha is limit?

mmm.. for example: $V_{\omega+1}$ contains $\omega$ but not $\omega_1$, wich is his "power"

Comment: @DanieleGambetta $\omega_1$ is *not* the powerset of $\omega$, or even necessarily it's powerset's cardinality!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have answered your own question, but let's elucidate a bit.

satisfies power and pairing but not infinity, as you mentioned.

So, to satisfy all three of them you need + that is the next limit ordinal. If you have +n, for n <   and you have a set X than P(X) and {X} is in the next level, +n+1, so you need a limit ordinal to satisfy pair and power.